# How to handle Spanish character in my App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding

In my app i have a service which supports spanish and return the result in spanish. 
Now i am trying to pass some search term to this service to get the result back but its failing because while sending compiler converts the word to some funny word with unidentified characters.
I am doing this:
name here is coming in spanish but when i am adding this in the config dictionary it gets converted again to some funny thing.

```
-(void)perfromLocationSearchWithName:(NSString *)name{

    NSData * nameCode = [[NSData alloc]init];
    nameCode = [name dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString * namePass = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:nameCode encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Name:%@",namePass);

    NSMutableDictionary *config = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:4] autorelease];
    NSString * strAction = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vendorSearchByName"];
    if (namePass !=nil){
        [config setObject:namePass forKey:@"vendorName"];
        //[config setObject:@"001" forKey:@"MakeCode"];
        [config setObject:@"5" forKey:@"maxCount"];
        [config setObject:strAction forKey:@"action"];
    }
    NSLog(@"Dict%@",[config description]);
    comm = [[CommManager alloc] init];
    [comm searchDealerLocationWithOptions:config withDelegate:self];
    [namePass release];
}
```

Please help 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Try using `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`. Helped us in our app.

Comment: It's still doing the same thing. The string namePass is giving me the exact string but when i add it to the config and nslog to check the result it the letter with accent is been replaced with 4-5 special characters